# how to scroll to view(TextView, ImageView..etc..) on button Click in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, listview, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

i'm using android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.

clickbutton in AppBarlayout into Toobar
my view structure

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

           ......
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
...
```

i want this..

1. button click
   , 2. scroll go to top

..

i tried

```
mNestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, targetScroll);
```

scroll is moved but this method only in moved NestedScrollview

no parent(CoordinatorLayout) scroll...

how do i ? is there reference?

Comment: [add description]1. buttonclick -> 2.scroll to view of location

Comment: You want to expand and collapse CollapsingToolbarLayout programmatically?

Comment: @AntonTarasov umm just scroll to top and expand